# Duplicating elements of vector based on variable from different dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset with monthly return of various stocks over a certain period of time where the months are already formatted to consecutively numbered month-ID. To compare those I have imported a .csv file with unique one-month interest rates during that time and saved it as a vector. Now, I want to add this vector to my datasaet. Problem is the difference in length.

My question is: how can I extend this vector to the length of my data by duplicating the elements such that every rate is correctly assigned to the corresponding month?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Hello procrastinator, please add sample data using `dput(head(df,20))`. Also include a "glimpse" of the data, sample code and expected output. Cheers and happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say the stock dataset is called `stocks` with a variable called `months`. and the interest vector dataset is called `interest`. I assume they're both in the same order, and have the same months,

Then add the months to the interests with `int_dat <- data.frame(months = unique(stocks$months), interest = interest)`. Add the months to the stocks data with `stocks_new <- merge(stocks, int_dat, by = 'month', all = TRUE)`.